# React Router v4 dynamic nested routes do not match

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I ask this question just want to make sure that I understand the dynamic nested routes in React Router v4 correctly. I want to build a hacker news client similar to [this one](https://react-hn.appspot.com/#/news). But I am bogged down by setting up the dynamic routes.

In React Router v4, if I follow other tutorials on the web using the `match` object I will have something like this (A super simple one):

```
const ChildComponent = ({rows, match}) => (
  <div>
    <ol>
      rows.map((row, i) => {
        return (
           <li key={row.id}>
            <a href={row.url}>row.title</a> // topic title
            <Link to=`${match.url}/${row.by}`>row.by</Link> // topic author
           </li>

        )
      }
    </ol>
    <Route path=`${match.url}/:userId` render={(props) => <UserProfile fetchUserData={fetchUserData} {...props} />} />
  </div>
)};
```

And when we render the parent component, we usually use something like this for routing:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" render={Home} />
    <Route path="/topics" render={(props) => <ChildComponent rows={rows} {...props} /> } />
    <Route path="*" render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
</Switch>
```

But this is not ideal for this case, as when I click to view the author's info I need to display a url like this: "http://mysite/user/userid" instead of the current one which is "http://mysite/news/userid".

However, if I change `${match.url}/${row.by}` to `/user/${row.by}` and change `${match.url}/:userId` to `/user/:userId` the route is not recognized in the app. The route begins with `/user/` is simply skipped, it will go straight to the app's NotFound route (if there is one), which is in the parent component. Why will the links in child component try to match the routes in the parent if I don't use `${match.url}` in the route?

I have added a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8216njzx70) for you to easier to understand this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you'll click the `/user/:userId:` link the app will parse the Router's `Switch` to see if something matches. If it doesn't it fallback to `*`.
In your case, you did not specify anything in the `Switch` to handle `/user` .

You'll need to move your *userId* `Route` declaration to the `Switch` as they won't share the same first route (`/user` !== `/topics`).

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" render={Home} />
    <Route path="/topics" render={(props) => <ChildComponent rows={rows} {...props} /> } />
    <Route path="/user/:userId" render={(props) => <UserProfile fetchUserData={fetchUserData} {...props} />} />
    <Route render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: But what should I render the path `/user`? There is no such page. I just want to make up the url middle part but apparently react router doesn't allow this.

Comment: Thanks I have thought about this approach too. But this is not ideal, as you can see in my demo I put the `fetchUserData` or whatever it is called in the child component `Container` and I don't want to expose it to the `App` component. I want to put all the async calls to the server in a separate component.

Comment: You can move the call to fetch user data to the method `componentDidMount` of the `UserProfile` component. Best of both worlds.

Comment: @AnaMariaCabrera Post a new question with your issue, not a comment ?